# Why free() for array of poiters does not deallocate memory?

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc, free

I'm trying to free memory after pointers array as in a following code:

```
int ** t = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*)*10000000);
printf("1\n");
getchar();
for(int i =0; i < 10000000; i++){
    t[i] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
    *t[i] = i;
}
printf("2\n");
getchar();

for(int i =0; i < 10000000; i++){
    free(t[i]);
}
printf("3\n");
getchar();

free(t);
printf("4\n");
getchar();
```

During the execution my system monitor shows me some strange values. When specific numbers are displayed (as in the code) i get following memory usage.

1. 148K
2. 390,540K
3. 390,540K
4. 312,676K

I'm a bit confused. Why numbers in 2 and 3 are the same? Am I doing something wrong, or system monitor is inaccurate? If it is fault of SM then why it noticed difference between 3 and 4?

Comment: On a virtual memory system, the system tends not to commit pages until you actually use the memory.  And `free` tends not to return memory to the OS.

Comment: " i get following memory usage" - from *where* ?? Taskman ?? The sub-allocator for your implementation may be keeping the memory in a free list, still allocated from the OS, but ready for another round of (now much faster) allocations.

Comment: The memory has been released to the heap, but the heap may not have released it to the system. It doesn't have to.

Comment: if you on linux run your program under valgrind. That will really tell you if the memory is released or not

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Do I cast the return of malloc ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `free()` depend on its underlying implementation. Most of the implementations of `free()`does not return the freed memory back to the OS but just gives the memory back to the pool, from which the `malloc` requests are satisfied, which simply means the freed memory is now available to reuse by the program. Check [**this**](http://c-faq.com/malloc/freetoOS.html).